# Show that if an infinite series with positive real-valued terms, $\sum{a_n}$, converges, so does the series $\sum{{a}_n^2}$

Tags: proof-verification, convergence-divergence, summation

The question I am trying to prove is exactly as the title states:

> Show that if an infinite series with positive real-valued terms,
>   $\sum{a_n}$, converges, so does the series $\sum{{a}_n^2}$.

I'm not sure if I am missing something, but it seems to me that $\lim \limits_{k \to \infty}{a_k} = 0$, implying $\lim \limits_{k \to \infty}{a^2_k} = 0$, from which we can deduce that $\sum{{a}_n^2}$ converges.

I am wondering if there are any errors in my logic, because I've found this class quite challenging up until now, but this seems too simple..

Comment: You reasoning is flawed... For example $\sum \frac 1n$ diverges. Instead you should note that $0\leq x^2\leq x$ whenever $0\leq x\leq 1$.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM I see what you mean. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum a_n$ converges

$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n=0$

$\implies 0\leq a_n \leq 1$ for large enough $n$

$\implies 0\leq a_n^2\leq a_n$

$\implies \sum a_n^2$ converges by comparison test.

Comment: Ahh.. I see what you're saying. I didn't consider things from that perspective. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $0 \leq a_n \leq 1$, we have $a_n^2 \leq a_n$.

If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $n_0$ exists such that, for $n \geq n_0$, we have $0\leq a_n \leq 1$.

So $\sum a_n^2 = \sum_{n=0}^{n_0-1} a_n^2 + \sum_{n=n_0}^{+ \infty} a_n^2 \leq \sum_{n=0}^{n_0-1} a_n^2 + \sum_{n=n_0}^{+ \infty} a_n$

Answer (score 0):

If $\sum_n^\infty a_n$ converges then its general term must converge to $0$ and so there must exist some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n\leq 1$ if $n\geq N$. Having into account that $a_n^2\leq a_n$ for those $n$ we get
$$
\sum_n^\infty a_n^2=\sum_{n<N}a_n^2+\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n^2\leq\sum_{n<N}a_n^2+\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n<\infty.
$$